# I don't understand P-Q system in GEB

Tags: formal-languages

Up front some apologies since I am not a mathematician and English is not my native language so it might be that I am missing some basics here. If so please don't flame me but just point me to some place where I might read up on basics first.

I am currently trying to read the [GEB book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach) to get some better understanding of mathematics and formal systems and so far I have found it quite readable. 
Now I expected that my lack of mathematical knowledge and English language might stop me at some point and unfortunately it has when I came up to the PQ chapter of the book.

I hope it is ok if I quote the relevant chapter in the book:

> The pq-System
>
> The  formal  system  of  this  Chapter  is  called  the  pq-system.  It  is  not  important  to 
>   mathematicians or logicians-in fact, it is just a simple invention of mine. Its importance 
>   lies only in the fact that it provides an excellent example of many ideas that play a large 
>   role in this book. There are three distinct symbols of the pq-system:
>
> p q -
>
> The letters p, q, and the hyphen.
>
> The pq-system has an infinite number of axioms. Since we can't write them all down, we 
>   have to have some other way of describing what they are. Actually, we want more than 
>   just a description of the axioms; we want a way to tell whether some given string is an 
>   axiom  or  not.  A  mere  description  of  axioms  might  characterize  them  fully  and  yet 
>   weakly-which  was  the  problem  with  the  way  theorems  in  the  MIU-system  were 
>   characterized.  We  don't  want  to  have  to  struggle  for  an  indeterminate-possibly  infinite 
>   length of time, just to find out if some string is an axiom or not. Therefore, we will define 
>   axioms  in  such  a  way  that  there  is  an  obvious  decision  procedure  for  axiomhood  of  a 
>   string composed of p's, q's, and hyphens.
>
> DEFINITION: xp-qx is an axiom, whenever x is composed of hyphens only.
>
> Note that 'x' must stand for the same string of hyphens in both occurrences For example, -
>   -p-q---is an axiom. The literal expression `xp-qx-' is not an axiom, of course (because 'x' 
>   does not belong to the pq-system); it is more like a mold in which all axioms are cast-and 
>   it is called an axiom schema. 
>   The pq-system has only one rule of production:
>
> RULE: Suppose x, y, and z all stand for particular strings containing only hyphens. And 
>   suppose that x py qz is known to be a theorem. The 'xpy-qz-' is a theorem.
>
> For example, take x to be'--', y to be'---', and z to be'-'. The rule tells us:
>
> If --p---q- turns out to be a theorem, then so will --p----q--.

After that the author asks the reader if he can come up with the decision procedure. One paragraph later the author states:

> The  criterion  for  theoremhood  is  that  the  first  two hyphen-groups should add up, in length, to the third hyphen-group.

Again, I am not a mathematician so if I am missing some basic knowledge to understand how author came up with this ... please tell me where I can find it. I just don't understand how he came up with that.

If i take the following axiom: 
    -----p-q--
and apply the given rule, I come up with
    -----p--q---

AFAIK ----- + -- do not equal ---.

I do not want to continue reading the book until I can understand this part. Please help me.

Comment: It seems the axioms should be xp-qx- and not xp-qx as in your displayed "DEFINITION". In the note immediately following the definition this is made clear, and also in the intent given by theormhood. We need x hyphens plus the one hyphen between p,q to equal the string x- having one more hyphen than x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of hyphens I'll use *'s since they're more readable.

The axioms then should be of the form $xp*qx*$ where both instances of x represent the same number of *'s. For example: $***p*q****$ is an axiom, saying that 3+1=4 (to get what an axiom or theorem is "saying", count the number of * before the p, add the number of * between the p and q, and that should equal the number of * after the q.

Your example (in * notation) of a proposed axiom is then $*****p*q**$. But this isn't an axiom because it has five * before the p and two * after the p.

Note that there's nothing wrong with the authors statement that "If $**p***q*$ turns out to be a theorem, etc" because in fact $**p***q*$ will *not* turn out to be a theorem. The author is just giving that as an example of applying the "rule" to get another theorem from one that already exists, and for $**p***q*$ that particular string will not turn out to be a theorem in the first place.

You can translate the rule :If $xpyqz$ is a theorem then $xpy*qz*$ is also a theorem, to mean that if x *'s plus y *' s equal z *' s, then also x *'s plus (y+1) *' s will equal (z+1) *' s.

At least that's how it looks like it goes.

Comment: Thank you. I was being blind and did not see that the axiom schema is xp-qx. I was looking at it and constantly seeing xp-qy. Duh, I feel stupid. Thank you for taking the time to write up an answer.

Comment: Be sure to check, but as I note I think the axiom schema should be xp-qx- (note the extra - at the end), and not what you have in this comment (or in main display of "DEFINITION", which was xp-qx (without the extra - at the end). It may be that in GEB there was a typo in the statement of the "DEFINITION" but it definitely needs the extra - at the end to be the correct definition of the axiom schema, which you can see by the author's example after the DEFINITION.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out what I was missing for half an hour then I understood `xp-qx` was missing a hyphen. We are probably reading the same pdf which seems to be a OCR judging by the typos (like `MI' system` on IV).